# SVG Transition is crashing chrome (css, html)

Tags: html, css, svg, css-transitions, svg-animate

I have a svg stroke-dasharray transition in my website on hover of an element, the problem is i hover on the element for 4-5 times, the page crashes/become unresponsive. Eventually i have to kill the page !! Anyone knows the issue ?

```css
div{
max-width: 200px;
background: tomato;
text-align:center;
}

svg {
  max-width: 100px;
  fill:none;
  stroke: #212121;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  transition-duration: 850ms;
}

div:hover svg {
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  stroke-dasharray:73;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 24;" xml:space="preserve">
<path class="download_st0" d="M21,15v4c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H5c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2v-4"/>
<polyline class="download_st0" points="7,10 12,15 17,10 "/>
<line class="download_st0" x1="12" y1="15" x2="12" y2="3"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The *issue* is a browser bug.

[Here is chromium's bug tracker.](https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/) Let them know about it.

Note that I could repro in both stable 71 and canary 73 on macOs.

Nothing much SO can do for you unfortunately...
If you wish to spend time helping the devs fix this quickly, you can run a [bisect](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py) to check which commit caused this bug, but once again this is a *browser bug*, so a bit off-topic for us.

Comment: Thanks for the insight to the browser bug

Answer (score 0):

Looks like converting to single-path `svg` helps:

```css
div {
  max-width: 200px;
  background: tomato;
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  max-width: 100px;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #212121;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  transition: .85s;
}

div:hover path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 73;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21 15v4c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2H5c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2v-4M7 10l5 5 5-5M12 15V3" class="download_st0"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Kosh, i tried the code that you provided but the issue still persists